# yii2: how to add fixed filter in SerachModel->search(...)

Tags: php, search, model, yii2

I'm quite new to Yii and I'm facing a little problem,
I would like to display a table already filtered adn allow the filter with query parameters string.

I declare a new action in Controller

```
public function actionIndexFiltered($candidateId)
{
    $searchModel = new CvRisorsaTitoloSearch();
    //$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search([$searchModel->formName() => ['is_cod_candidato' => $candidateId]]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

This code works but it doesen't allow filter with query paramters.

'CvRisorsaTitolo' is a "many to many" table with other information,
and 'is_cod_candidato' is a field of 'CvRisorsaTitolo'.

Hiow can I combine my filter and filter of query parameters ion other fileds "Yii::$app->request->queryParams".

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well that sounds easy - you just merge your query data an predefined data:

```
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    Yii::$app->request->queryParams,
    [$searchModel->formName() => ['is_cod_candidato' => $candidateId]]
));
```

If you put predefined data as a first argument it may be redefined by user request.